# Can I "fake" a thread with the emterpreter?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, pthreads, emscripten

I'm porting a project to emscripten.  The project has several noncritical threads that just do a couple low priority things.  Speed of the thread function is not an issue.  However, they do need to happen without blocking the program.

I'm using EMTERPRETIFY and whitelisting these noncritical functions.

Is there a call I can do to emulate threading with the emterpreter?  I.E. devote a couple cycles to the threaded function, then go back to the main program?

I thought I was going to use emscripten_async_call, but it looks like that will block until the function is complete, once it gets fired.

Is there a way to have my emterpreted function run alongside?

Answer (score 1):

Some options I know about:

First, you can manually convert

```
void *thread_fn(void *) {
  // init
  while (true) {
    // do work
  }
}
```

into initialization and work functions (and optionally the third glue function for the original case), then serialize execution manually (just as you have written): invoke one "work function", then another one, then first again, etc.

Another option, a semi automatic way that may succeed: with [GNU Pth](https://www.gnu.org/software/pth/) you can emulate multithreading inside the single OS thread. As I can imagine, it is done precisely with coroutines. If you succeed in porting GNU Pth to Emscripten's coroutines, then you would automatically get emulated threads switched implicitly at some syscalls (?). I'm still unsure on this approach, but if you will port this library to Emscripten, you would probably get enough information how to separate the main high-priority thread.

Personally I have used the first approach while porting QEMU to Emscripten (and it worked but with some glitches). The second approach was used by me for single-threading a native code, but I never used it with Emscripten, so *you have been warned* :) -- it is quite promising but it needs some work that may end up just with spent time... Anyway, it looks like serializing some multithreaded code is not some straightforward task that definitely succeed, it depends...

Meanwhile, there were already a shared memory mutli-threading support in browsers. AFAIK, it was re-disabled after Meltdown & Spectre. I don't know whether it was already re-enabled (if it is possibly at all).

Comment: Thanks for the info... I will look into your suggestions year.  I didn't want to port a whole separate library though... was just hoping I wasn't finding the keyword.  It seems strange to write a whole custom virtual machine and not throw in multithreading-- even if it would be slow.

Comment: Maybe they consider multithreading as already present natively... I don't know about its current state, but AFAIK it was working some time ago (see Emscripten's pthread implementation).